# Чтение файлов в хронологическом порядке. Имя файла = дата создания файла

Tags: php

В директории имеются текстовые файлы с именами типа 01012016.txt, 02012016, 03012016... 13092020 и т.д., т.е. в каждый файл пишутся все сообщения за сутки и создается файл. Имя файла - дата.txt. Собственно вопрос: требуется выполнять обработку файлов за несколько лет, которые лежат в одной директории. Читаем содержимое всех файлов и пишем результат в один файл.  Подскажите как сделать сортировку массива, чтобы читались файлы в хронологическом порядке, т.е. как они были созданы: 01012016.txt, 02012016, 03012016 ... 13092020, а не 01012016.txt, 01012017.txt, 01012018.txt, 01012019.txt, 01012020.txt.

```
<?php
$dir="./msg"; // директория с файлами
$files=scandir($dir); // сканируем директорию и помещаем результат в массив $files
array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'
// Вывод содержимого массива
foreach($files as $spisok){
  echo ("<center>".$spisok."</center>");
}
$fw=fopen("./all_msg.txt", "w+"); // Создаем файл в который будем писать всю информацию a+ - дописывать в конец файла, w+ - очищать файл перед записью
foreach ($files as $file){ // В цикле обрабатываем файлы
$fp=fopen($dir."/".$file, "r"); // Открываем файл в режиме чтения
 if($fp){
    //Считываем файл построчно в переменную stringtext
     while(!feof($fp)){
     $stringtext=fgets($fp);  // Читаем строку из файла
      if(!empty($stringtext)){
      $stringtext=iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", $stringtext);// Меняем кодировку текста (исходный файл сохранен в cp1251)
       // Разбираем строку
       $date=substr($stringtext,0,10); // Вырезаем 10 символов из строки начиная с 0 символа
       $time=substr($stringtext,11,10); // Вырезаем 10 символов из строки начиная с 11 символа
       $mes=substr($stringtext,strlen($date." ".$time)); // Остаток строки помещеем в переменную $mes
       $mes=trim($mes); // Удаляем пробелы в начале и конце строки
       $result=$date." ".$time." ".$mes."\r\n"; // Результат для записи в файл
       $result_html="<tr class='str'><td>".$date."</td><td>".$time."</td><td>".$mes."</td></tr>"; // Результат для вывода в браузере
       fwrite($fw, $result); // записываем текст в созданный файл
      }
     // Уничтожаем переменныеt
     unset($stringtext);
     unset($result);
    }
 }
 else {
     echo("Ошибка при открытии файла");
 }
fclose($fp);
unset($fp);
}
fclose($fw); // закрываем созданный файл
unset($files);
unset($file);
unset($fw);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```php
<?php

$files=[
    "01012016.txt", "01012017.txt",
    "01012018.txt", "01012019.txt",
    "01012020.txt", "01012016.txt",
    "02012016.txt", "03012016.txt",
    "13092020.txt"
];


print_r($files);

// преобразуем в список объектов
$files = array_map(function($file){
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->file = $file;
    
    // получим имя файла
    $file_name = pathinfo($file)['filename'];
    // инвертируем строку с датой
    $obj->date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
        'dmY', $file_name)->format('Ymd');
    return $obj;
}, $files);

// отсортируем по полю "дата"
uasort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->date, $b->date);
});


print_r($files);
```

[Посмотреть результат](https://ideone.com/OUhK4J)

Получить отсортированный список файлов:

```php
$sorted_files = [];

foreach($files as $f)
{
    $sorted_files[] = $f->file;
}

print_r($sorted_files);
```

[Посмотреть результат](https://ideone.com/TeyLSo)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сортировка работает как надо. Подскажите как на выходе получить массив, точно такой же как на входе, только отсортированный.

Comment: @Александр, добавил.